# com.evermind.server.ejb.StatelessSessionDefaultRemoteHome

Tags: jakarta-ee

I need to migrate ejb 3.0 from oracle appserver 10.x deployment files to  ejb 3.1 with weblogic 12.x app server.

The old code is in oc4j(Oracle app server). In ejb-jar.xml file for each session bean, the home interface 'com.evermind.server.ejb.StatelessSessionDefaultRemoteHome' is defined. Example:

```
<enterprise-beans>
    <session>
        <display-name>Helloworld</display-name>
        <ejb-name>Helloworldsession</ejb-name>
        <home>com.evermind.server.ejb.StatelessSessionDefaultRemoteHome</home>
        <remote>com.examples.HelloRemote</remote>
        <ejb-class>com.examples.HelloWorldSessionBean</ejb-class>
        <session-type>stateless</session-type>
        <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
    </session>
</enterprise-beans>
```

What does com.evermind.server.ejb.StatelessSessionDefaultRemoteHome do ? What is the substitute for this in Weblogic ? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks more like migrating from J2EE 1.4? It has nothing to do with either OC4J or WebLogic, but with a completely renewed programming model starting with EJB3.0.

With EJB3 you won't need either home interfaces, nor extending classes, nor specifying stuff within long deployment descriptors. If you google for "migrating ejb 2 to ejb 3", you'll find many hints, for example [this one](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071804/java-web-development/migrating-ejb-2-x-applications-to-ejb-3-0.html).

Besides that, you should take a look at the [Java EE 6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/) in part IV on how to implement EJBs in version 3.1.

Comment: @user3791049: Since you are new to StackOverflow - if the answer is helpful for you, consider voting it up and/or accepting it.